# How to connect Oracle 19c Database

Tags: oracle, containers, oracle19c

I am trying to connect to pluggable databases previously created and could not do it.

**Option 1**

```
SQL> conn /as sysdba;
    Connected.
    SQL> conn system/system
    ERROR:
    ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
    Process ID: 0
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
    
    
    Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
    SQL>
```

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

/

**Option 2**

```
SQL> show pdbs;
SQL> conn / as sysdba;
Connected.
SQL> show pdbs;
SQL> alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
alter pluggable database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open
```

Previously I had connected using sql developer and worked.

**Updated**

My database is not mounted and I tried to mount it and shows the below error details.

```
   SQL> conn / as sysdba;
    Connected.
    SQL> show con_name;
    
    CON_NAME
    ------------------------------
    CDB$ROOT
    SQL> select open_mode from v$database;
    select open_mode from v$database
                          *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01507: database not mounted
    
    
    SQL> alter database mount;
    alter database mount
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00214: control file
    'E:\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\PROD\CONTROLFILE\O1_MF_JCWYX5LY_.CTL' version
    102600 inconsistent with file
    'E:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\PROD\CONTROLFILE\O1_MF_JCWYX5BQ_.CTL' version 102597
    
    
    SQL> show parameter control
    
    NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
    ------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
    control_file_record_keep_time        integer     7
    control_files                        string      E:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\PROD\CON
                                                     TROLFILE\O1_MF_JCWYX5BQ_.CTL,
                                                     E:\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AR
                                                     EA\PROD\CONTROLFILE\O1_MF_JCWY
                                                     X5LY_.CTL
    control_management_pack_access       string      DIAGNOSTIC+TUNING
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the CDB is at MOUNT, not OPEN, you should open the root container before using PDB.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

OPEN_MODE
--------------------
MOUNTED
```

To open the CDB, you may issue the following SQL command or bounce it.

```
SQL> alter database open;

Database altered.
```

Then show pdbs again.

```
SQL> show pdbs;

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 ORCLPDB                        READ WRITE NO
```

If the PDB is still MOUNTED, then you should open it.

```
SQL> alter pluggable database orclpdb open;

Pluggable database altered.
```

Comment: Shows the following error after i tried your answer ORA-00214: control file
'E:\APP\ORACLE\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\PROD\CONTROLFILE\O1_MF_JCWYX5LY_.CTL' version
102600 inconsistent with file
'E:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\PROD\CONTROLFILE\O1_MF_JCWYX5BQ_.CTL' version 102597

Comment: ORA-00214 is another issue, your database is unable to open normally at this moment. You should try to make your controlfiles consistent first.